# Can past simple mean annoyance in my example

Tags: past-tense

I really worry because I have not received my order (made on 30/10/21). I **already contacted** you in December for the same reason  and  I only got a reply in January after sending  many  emails  .

You answered   that you were  going to do it or had just done  it , but did not give  any proof of it . So have you sent it ?There must be a tracking or a picture of the parcel

Just would like to know if I could have written **had already contacted** to express my annoyance .I  think  it could be possible even if the tense that comes after present perfect is past simple and it is written when it happened .I think choosing  past simple did not give a big weight to my annoyance .

Comment: Tenses do not give weight to annoyance: they indicate the order in which things happened.  In this case, present simple is the correct tense. This link gives some useful tips about adding emphasis to your writing https://www.thoughtco.com/achieving-emphasis-in-writing-3972773

Comment: but past perfect emphasizes the event and my event is in the past so why present?

Comment: I think @JavaLatte meant to say **simple past**, present simple does not work in this situation.

Comment: To express annoyance you need vocabulary,  compare 1. "We disliked the movie" 2. "We hated the movie" 3. "We wasted hard earned money buying tickets for what was one of the worst movies we have ever had the misfortune to see." Which of these three sentences express the strongest disapproval?

Comment: Past perfect does **not** emphasize the event: it places the event in the sequence of events.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thanks for correcting that error in my comment.  

Answer (score 0):

The past perfect would be possible but not mandatory.

It is possible be cause your second sentence can be understood as describing the actions in January

> I had already contacted you prior to receiving an email from you.

But since you are really just describing a sequence of events in chronological order you don't need past perfect.  Simple past is fine

> In December I contacted you. Then in January, I received an email.

There is no explicit "frustration" expressed by either of these.

Comment: Why did you cancel already?   I can't write' In December I already contacted you' . Already is for me a way of expressing my annoyance to show that it is  the second time I have tried to get in touch

Comment: "I have already contacted you about this - in December - and I only got a reply in January..."

Comment: but if you know  that the time of the event  belongs to the past (December) isn't it better to use past simple. I thought already can go with past simple

Comment: "Why did you cancel already"  I've written simplified sentences that show both grammatical forms are possible. You can add "already" and other modifiers as you wish.  However, given the context, you probably shouldn't assume that subtle clues to your frustration will be understood.  The best way to express frustration is not "already" but "I am extremely frustrated with the poor service that I have received".    Remember "explicit is better than implicit" if you want to avoid being misunderstood.

Comment: but I was not extremely frustrated but more disappointed

Comment: Okay then ...  "I was disappointed by the poor service...."

Comment: "I have already contacted you about this - in December - and I only got a reply in January. What do you think about present perfect here? Is it better than past simple or past perfect .

Comment: @user5577 As is being implied here, while your original is perfectly understandable, in a couple of respects it does lack the idiomacy of a native speaker. My own way of writing it would be: *Despite my contacting you about this in December, I am increasingly concerned that my order of 31/10/21 has still not been delivered. After many further emails from me,  and your reply in January stating that delivery was imminent, I still do not have the goods. Have they been sent? If so there must be a tracking picture.*

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree with others who have pointed out that the past simple is correctly used here. But although your letter is perfectly intelligible with no obvious grammar mistakes, it is clear on reading it that it has been written by a non-native speaker - albeit a very good English speaker.

I know that writing advice is off-limits here, but I am happy in this instance to write the letter in a way that it might be written by a native English speaker.

How about the following:

*I am now becoming most concerned that my order placed on 30/10/21 has still not been received. I contacted you about this in December and only got your reply in January, after many emails on my part.*

*You indicated either that you had sent it or were about to do so - though you supplied no proof. So have you sent it or haven't you? Do you have any tracking or picture evidence of the parcel, that you can let me have?*